# Disable sound on error messages?

Tags: sound, system-settings

Sometimes during my workflow, an error will occur. Any kind of system error, browser error, etc. When this happens, a nice little message dialog appears and tells me exactly what has happened or what went wrong.

However -

It is also accompanied by a loud, obnoxious and sudden noise.

Maybe to normal users, this is tolerable. Errors happen.

But when you've been coding for 18 hours straight to pure silence / soft music and this monstrosity occurs - well you could end up flinching and falling backwards out of your chair (which may or may not have happened just 10 minutes ago.)

Can I mute, or otherwise change this sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable event sounds from Ubuntu Tweak.If you haven't installed it then you can do it by

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Then after installing it , type as Ubuntu and it will display the tweak Icon and from the tweaks as shown in the image you can disable them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just mute the speakers. You can do this by:

Press Fn+F7 (In my case it's this, if it is not this then look at the 'F''s and you should see a button with a Speaker crossed over it)

Or the simplest way: Just mute it from the menu.

Hope this helps you! :-)

Comment: The problem with this is it mutes everything - I'm looking to just disable the sound that accompanies the error messages.